# imagemagick error when run from bash script on Mac OSX

Tags: bash, macos, imagemagick

I want to run the following script in bash 3.2.57(1):

```
#!/bin/bash
basename=abc
convert  $basename.pdf $basename.png
```

I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /ImageMagick-7.0.8/lib/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/XXX/Applications/ImageMagick-7.0.8/bin/convert
  Reason: image not found
./batch_convert.sh: line 22: 46228 Abort trap: 6           convert $basename.pdf $basename.png
```

When I run the same 2 commands (setting the variable and `convert`), I get no error.

Why is this happening?

Comment: basename is a bash shell function. "return filename portion of pathname". So it is likely a reserved word. See the man pages for base name. Also in ImageMagick 7, use magick, not convert. Also best to put quotes around strings.

Comment: @fmw42 made those 2 corrections, still the same error.
'basenamex=abc'
'magick  "$basenamex.pdf" "$basenamex.png"'

Comment: What is your new command? Where did you get ImageMagick and how did you install it? What do you get from `magick -version` in a terminal window (not in a script). Does `magick abc.pdf abc.png` work in a terminal window (not in a script)? Do you have Ghostscript installed?

Comment: I think I might have downloaded it. I get
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.8-9 Q16 x86_64 2018-08-04 https://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2018 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI
Delegates (built-in): bzlib freetype jng jpeg lcms png raw tiff webp xml zlib

Comment: Your error message shows a different command than what you said you used.

Comment: Downloaded it from where? If you do not know how/where you got it and installed it, then perhaps you should discard it and try again from binary. Perhaps you installed from source and have no delegates installed. That is why I asked about `magick -version`. You can get a binary from Homebrew, for example.

Comment: Yes, I have removed "-transparent white" to make a minimal failing example. When I run an imagemagick command from the terminal, it works just fine.

Comment: Then show the exact command you are currently using. Change basename to something else.

Comment: xxx=abc
magick  "$xxx.pdf" "$xxx.png"
This works in the terminal, and fails when running it from the script.

Comment: What did you name your script and how did you call it in a terminal window. You do not just copy and paste that.

Comment: `xxx=abc magick "$xxx.pdf" "$xxx.png"` That is improper syntax.  Try `xxx='abc'` then `magick $xxx.pdf $xxx.png` in a terminal, not in a script.

Comment: I named the script "batch_convert.sh" and I call it as "./batch_convert.sh"

Comment: That command works in terminal, just like the commands before. The problem is in the script.

Comment: See my answer below and let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Using IM 7.0.8.59 Q16 Mac OSX Sierra, this works for me.

**create a pdf**

```
magick logo: logo.pdf
```

**create a script called test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

xxx="logo"
magick $xxx.pdf $xxx.png
```

**run script by typing its name in a bash terminal**

```
bash test.sh
```

[image]

Try that and report if that works. I was working from my desktop. So the script and pdf file were on my desktop.

Note that logo: (with the colon) is an ImageMagick internal image. So it is available from anywhere.

Comment: the command `bash test.sh` fails with error
`dyld: Library not loaded: /ImageMagick-7.0.8/lib/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/XXX/Applications/ImageMagick-7.0.8/bin/magick
  Reason: image not found
test.sh: line 4: 47451 Abort trap: 6           magick $xxx.pdf $xxx.png`

Comment: I do not know why it fails for you. It works fine for me. What is your exact version of ImageMagick 7.x.x.x and what do you get from `magick -version`? Does those IM commands work by typing or pasting into a terminal?

Comment: Thank you. 
`Version: ImageMagick 7.0.8-9 Q16 x86_64 2018-08-04 https://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2018 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI
Delegates (built-in): bzlib freetype jng jpeg lcms png raw tiff webp xml zlib`

Comment: You do not have Ghostscript installed. It should list as `gs` or `gslib` in the list of Delegates. Your IM version is rather old. Perhaps you should reinstall and include Ghostscript.

Comment: `which gs` does in fact return `/usr/local/bin/gs`

Comment: What do you get from `magick -list configure | grep DELEGATES`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197461/discussion-between-fmw42-and-toniaz).