# How to properly install ImageMagick on Mac OSX Mojave without a package manager

Tags: bash, macos, imagemagick, macos-mojave, dylib

I am having issues running ImageMagick functions from a bash script, **but not from bash**. It was suggested to me to remove and reinstall ImageMagick. See [imagemagick error when run from bash script on Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57349001/1011320) for my original post.

All installations seem to require Homebrew, but bash is complaining about security issues when I run `sudo brew`. Is there no other way of installing ImageMagick? The way I have installed is according to the instructions at https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php:

1. Download the tar file
2. Extract the tar to `~/Applications`
3. Add ImageMagick paths as exports in `~/.bashrc`

   `export MAGICK_HOME="$HOME/Applications/ImageMagick-7.0.8"
   export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$MAGICK_HOME/lib/"
   export PATH="$PATH:$MAGICK_HOME/bin"`

EDIT: I just noticed that `echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` prints nothing when it is inside a script.

Comment: AFAIK, **homebrew** isn't intended to be used with `sudo` ... and shouldn't be so used.

Comment: As per the link you have suggested, the package recommends `macports` i guess for mac and I see a port of that is available on [here](https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=ImageMagick).

Comment: re **edit** : it should at least output `/lib/`, right? Are you sure it is spelled right and protected from any other text that might change the variable name, i.e. `echo ${DYLD_LIB_PATH}/other/Stuff` (you need the `{..}`s in a case like this.) .Good luck.

Comment: @shellter When I run `echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` from bash command line, I get the path to ImageMagick's lib directory. When I put that command in a shell script and call the script from bash, nothing is outputed -- more like an empty line.

Comment: you need to find which of the shell's `.rc` files sets that value. Then after the first line of your script  add `source $HOME/.bashrc` (or whatever `.rc` file it is (may not be named with `rc`)). Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

I was having a very similar issue with my Mojave build installing and running ImageMagick-7.0.10. I was able to solve it doing 2 things.

1. You need to tell your terminal where the ImageMagick-X.X.XX folder is and where to find the libaries. I did this by running `sudo nano $HOME/.bash_profile` and adding the `export` commands at the bottom of the file, like this.

```
export MAGICK_HOME="/your/path/to/ImageMagick-7.0.10"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$MAGICK_HOME/lib/"
export PATH="$PATH:$MAGICK_HOME/bin"
```

2. I was still getting errors related to missing libraries so I did some googling which eventually led me to this GitHub issue https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/issues/503. Basically explaining that X11 on Mac you need to install [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org) separately.Just download and run the installer. It requires a system restart afterward but after that I was good to go.

### Test that it works

```
magick logo: logo.gif
identify logo.gif
display logo.gif
```